# html table width with percents

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a question. 
I am testing out a table.  This will eventually be with ASP.net but for now I'm just using JSFiddle to get the styling and everything done. 
But I came across something inexplicable (at least for me).

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9RdS/)

So I am setting the widths of my columns, and I am equaling 100%:

```
<table id="UndergradTable">
    <col style="width:20%"/>
    <col style="width:60%"/>
    <col style="width:20%"/>
    <thread>
    .... 
</table>
```

If I change the numbers to `22, 56, and 22`, (which also add up to 100%), the whole table actually shrinks in size instead of just the middle section. 
Is there a reason why this should happen?

Comment: In your jsfiddle I adjusted the widths as you show and it did what I expected: columns 1 and 3 got a little wider, column 2 narrower, and the whole table width remained the width of the Window.

Comment: on mine the whole thing shrunk by about 2 cm total

Comment: What browser? I'm using Firefox 27.0.1. Also see what happens if you maximize your browser window so that there's no cell text wrap going on and see if the behavior is different.

Comment: newest version of chrome.

Comment: You need to make the frame holding the rendered table quite wide in order to see the effect.

Comment: I ran the Firefox window at a reasonable size, not maximized, had some cell text wrap, and it still behaved as the OP expected. Some browsers seem to manage this differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a table is `width: auto`, each cell is as narrow as possible while still being wide enough to:

- support the width constraints in the CSS
- hold all the content of the cell
- not cause the table to horizontally overflow its container

The text in the right most column is the widest. When you make the relative width of the first two cells smaller in comparison to the right most, the entire table shrinks while the right most cell stays the same size.

Comment: it makes sense in a strange kind of way

Answer (score 1):

Because of 3. column text: "**Sergeant McAngryFace**"

This text from 2 line want to 1 line with change from 20 60 20 to 22 56 22.

Or use without space `&nbsp;` for non breaking space and all will 1 lines

Try to change:

```
"Sergeant McAngryFace" to
"Sergeant&nbsp;McAngryFace"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a reason you don't want to, why not set the table width to 100%? Such as:

```
<table id="UndergradTable" style="width:100%">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9RdS/4/)

Comment: normally i would, But my boss wants each column to have their own designated width so that it cannot scale in size.

Comment: Does that mean you're looking for static column widths then? Perhaps designating the widths in pixels or ems would be preferable then.

I mean, if you set a column to have a width of say 20% without the table having a width, what exactly is it 20% of?

Comment: it's going to be within a static floating div, so once the size it set 20% will always be a set number of pixels. but i know what you mean